# Move label and text box to left in Gridbaglayout

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

Can anybody of you good people to help me, I just cannot to move txtIPAddress and label ip Address to left, it is cutted now. I tried to experiment with weightx 0 to 1, ipadx but it didn't help. This is my function for red panel. Any help please ?

[image]

```
pnlCom=new JPanel();
        pnlCom.setBackground(Color.red);
        pnlCom.setSize(460,160);
        pnlCom.setLocation(10, 60);

        add(pnlCom);
        //add(pnlTcp);
        add(pnlCommon);
        GridBagLayout gb=new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gc=new GridBagConstraints();
        pnlCom.setLayout(gb);

        jLabelcommPort = setJLabel("Com Port : ");
        jLabelbaudRate = setJLabel("Baud Rate : ");
        jLabelplcAddress = setJLabel("Plc Address : ");
        jLabelsendTime = setJLabel("<html>Send Time : <br/>x 50 ms (2 - 99)</html>");
        jLabelx50 = setJLabel(" x 50 ms (2 - 99)");
        jComboBoxcommPort = setJComboBox(commPortList);
        jComboBoxbaudRate = setJComboBox(bitRateList);
        jTextAreaPlcAddress = setJTextField("");
        jTextAreaSendTime = setJTextField("");
        lblComType=setJLabel("Com type : ");
        cmbComType=setJComboBox(comType);
        lblIPAddress=setJLabel("IP Address : ");
        txtIPAddress=setJTextField("");



        gc.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);
        gc.ipadx = 80; 
        gc.weightx = 0.25;
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        pnlCom.add(jLabelcommPort,gc);

        gc.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);
        gc.ipadx = 80; 
        gc.weightx = 0.25;
        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        pnlCom.add(jComboBoxcommPort,gc);




        gc.insets=new Insets(10,0,0,0);
        gc.ipadx=80;
        gc.weightx = 0.5;
        gc.gridx=0;
        gc.gridy=1;
        gc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        pnlCom.add(jLabelbaudRate,gc);


        gc.insets=new Insets(10,0,0,0);
        gc.ipadx=80;
        gc.weightx = 0.5;
        gc.gridx=1;
        gc.gridy=1;
        gc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        pnlCom.add(jComboBoxbaudRate,gc);


        gc.insets=new Insets(10,0,0,0);
        gc.ipadx=80;
        gc.weightx = 0.5;
        gc.gridx=0;
        gc.gridy=2;
        gc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        pnlCom.add(lblComType,gc);


        gc.insets=new Insets(10,0,0,0);
        gc.ipadx=80;
        gc.weightx = 0.25;
        gc.gridx=1;
        gc.gridy=2;
        gc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        pnlCom.add(cmbComType,gc);








        gc.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);
        gc.ipadx = 80; 
        gc.weightx = 0.25;
        gc.gridx = 2;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        pnlCom.add(lblIPAddress,gc);

        gc.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);
        gc.ipadx = 80; 
        gc.weightx = 0.25;
        gc.gridx = 3;
        gc.gridy = 0;
        gc.anchor=GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        pnlCom.add(txtIPAddress,gc);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set ipadx=0 for all `JLabels`. One more thing is to reduce all the insets. You have left inset=10 for all controls. Try to set them to 5.